# Open and close socket when not using for communication, only using select() in language C

Tags: c, sockets, p2p

I'm writing a peer 2 peer chat application using TCP. This application includes client and server part in one file. I'm using `select()` without using `fork()`, `pthread` to handle connections. This is my mechanism of application, I run the application on a same host by running application on different terminals:

1. Initialize the first node, let say P1, as `./p2p portToListen`.

   - This node will open a socket on `portToListen`, let say ServerSock1, to listen connections from other peers. 
     And then it goes to a while loop with a `select()` function to wait for events.
2. Initialize the second node, let say P2, as `./p2p portToListen portToConnectTo` (I don't specify IP address here since I'm running on a local machine).

   - This also opens a new socket, let say ServerSock2, on "portToListen" as the first one, opens a new socket, let say ClientSock2 to connect to the first one. And then goes into the while loop.
   - When P2 connects to P1, at P1, it also accepts a new connection with a socket, ClientSock1.
3. After some phases for setting network information and exchanging configuration of the network(P1 sends information of current group to P2 and waits for ACK from P2), they are able to send chatting messages.

My question is, in this case, do I need to close the socket every time a peer sends/receives configuration information(not chatting message). For example, after P1 sends information of current group, do I need to close both ServerSock1 and ClientSock1, and after P2 sends ACK, do I need to close both ServerSock2 and ClientSock2? I think, ServerSock1,2 should always be opened? And only be closed outside of while loop?

If I do that, `select()` will not work since there is no socket to monitor events. When two peers would like to send chatting message, they need to open sockets again for Server side and Client side, send information to set up a new connection, by calling (`socket()`, `bind()`, `listener()`, `accept()`, `connect()`), send some chatting messages and `close()` sockets again.

Furthermore, if I want to send a broadcasting messages to other peers in a same group, I need to open sockets of peers again, send a chatting message and `close()` every socket?

In general, since I'm using only `select()`, what is a correct way to `close()` and open sockets? If it's possible, can you give me a general scenario for this? I really appreciate for your any comments. Thanks very much. Below is my general code:

```
int main(void)
{
int sock;
fd_set socks;
fd_set readsocks;
int maxsock;
int reuseaddr = 1; /* True */
struct addrinfo hints, *res;

/* Get the address info */
memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
if (getaddrinfo(NULL, PORT, &hints, &res) != 0) {
    perror("getaddrinfo");
    return 1;
}

/* Create the socket */
sock = socket(res->ai_family, res->ai_socktype, res->ai_protocol);
if (sock == -1) {
    perror("socket");
    return 1;
}

/* Enable the socket to reuse the address */
if (setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &reuseaddr, sizeof(int)) == -1) {
    perror("setsockopt");
    return 1;
}

/* Bind to the address */
if (bind(sock, res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen) == -1) {
    perror("bind");
    return 1;
}

freeaddrinfo(res);

/* Listen */
if (listen(sock, BACKLOG) == -1) {
    perror("listen");
    return 1;
}

/* Set up the fd_set */
FD_ZERO(&socks);
FD_SET(sock, &socks);
FD_SET(0, &socks);
maxsock = sock;

if (argc > 2) 
{
  clientSock2 = ConnectToServer(IPaddres, portToConnect);
  FD_SET(clientSock2, &socks);
}

/* Main loop */
while (1) {
    unsigned int s;
    readsocks = socks;
    if (select(maxsock + 1, &readsocks, NULL, NULL, NULL) == -1) {
        perror("select");
        return 1;
    }
    for (s = 0; s <= maxsock; s++) {
        if (FD_ISSET(s, &readsocks)) {
            printf("socket %d was ready\n", s);
            if (s == sock) {
                /* New connection */
                int clientSock1;
                struct sockaddr_in their_addr;
                size_t size = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
                clientSock1 = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&their_addr, &size);
                if (newsock == -1) {
                    perror("accept");
                }
                else {
                    printf("Got a connection from %s on port %d\n", 
                            inet_ntoa(their_addr.sin_addr), htons(their_addr.sin_port));
                    FD_SET(clientSock1, &socks);
                    if (clientSock1 > maxsock) {
                        maxsock = clientSock1;
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                /* Handle send, recv() information of network */
                handle(s, &socks);
            }
        }
    }
    if (FD_ISSET(0, &readset) { // Handle input
    // Sending chatting message 
    }
}

close(sock);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: TCP doesn't support broadcast.  Your choices for broadcast are either to send a broadcast UDP packet, or send the same data via unicast (TCP or UDP) to every other client.  The broadcast UDP method will be the easier way.

Comment: It sounds like you're in way over your head, trying to write code to handle a number of connections at once when you're not comfortable with the basic lifecycle of a single TCP connection.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner, actually, this is just a general code, I need to store a list of client sockets which are opened and send broadcast by calling a for loop over the list. I choose TCP since it is more reliable than UDP. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 2):

You should reuse the same connection. You may need to adjust your protocol so you know exactly where a request and a response finish and a new one starts.

Comment: what do you mean reuse the same connection since every time, after finish communication among peers, I would like to close() the socket, it would be freed up.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't have to `close()` anything unless you want to terminate a connection or stop listening for new ones.

The `listen()` socket will continue to listen for new connection attempts even after you `accept()` one, just keep checking for new connections with `select()` and `accept()` them aswell, you don't have to recreate this socket.

An estabilished TCP session is a two-way stream of data where you can safely `send()` and `recv()` multiple times as long as you need to communicate with that peer. Reconnecting after each block of information is pointless.

Use `select()` in the accepted connections too to check if there is information ready to `recv()`.

Note you have to rebuild the `fd_set` every time you call `select()` on it. The way your code it doing it is wrong.

Comment: this is a general code, I already do the stuffs as fd_set, send broadcast messages,... As far as I know, close socket every time of finishing a communication among nodes to free up resource and it's a good behavior. So, following you, in TCP, it not necessary to close sockets() and we only close it when a peer quits or crashed by some reasons? Thanks very much for your answer

Comment: From my current code, I keep all connections opened all the time and I only want to open a connection when I need it. Thanks very much